# Firebase writing data with variable via REST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

in my app I am getting the uid of the current user by:
also I get the username from : 
console.log gives me the right name.
But when I try to write to my db via:
        `https://movieapp-8a157.firebaseio.com/users/${username}/${authUser}/posts.json?auth=${token}`
It doesnt work. If I remove the ${username} it will write in the correct path. Any ideas? I edited my post for more clearness.

```
  export const postJob = data => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const randomColors = ["#f3a683"];
    const colorNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    const bgColor = randomColors[colorNumber];

    const val = getState();
    const userId = val.auth.userId;

    const rules = {
      description: "required|min:2"
    };

    const messages = {
      required: field => `${field}  is required`,

      "description.min": "job description is too short"
    };

    try {
      await validateAll(data, rules, messages);

      const token = await firebase
        .auth()
        .currentUser.getIdToken(true)
        .then(function(idToken) {
          return idToken;
        });

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          var displayName = user.displayName;
          var email = user.email;
          var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
          var photoURL = user.photoURL;
          var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
          var uid = user.uid;
          var providerData = user.providerData;
          // ...
        } else {
          // User is signed out.
          // ...
        }
      });
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      const authUser = user.uid;
      const username = await firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users/" + authUser + "/name")
        .once("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log("################", snapshot.val());
        });

      //console.log("#####################", authUser);
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://movieapp-8a157.firebaseio.com/users/${username}/${authUser}/posts.json?auth=${token}`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            titel: data.titel,
            fname: data.fname,
            description: data.description,
            cover: data.cover,
            friend: data.friend,
            ownerId: userId,

            bgColor: bgColor
          })
        }
      );

      const resData = await response.json();
```

Comment: where is the line that writes to db more exactly?

Comment: const response = await fetch(
        `https://movieapp-8a157.firebaseio.com/users/${username}/${authUser}/posts.json?auth=${token}`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            titel: data.titel,
            fname: data.fname,
            description: data.description,
            cover: data.cover,
            friend: data.friend,
            ownerId: userId,

            bgColor: bgColor
          })
        }
      );

Comment: got it, but where is this statement in your code?

Comment: updated my code in my first post

Answer (score 0):

Your code that's getting the UID isn't working the way you exepct.  The auth state listener is asynchronous and is triggering **after** the line of code that `accessesfirebase.auth().currentUser`.  That line of code is actually giving you the current user before the sign-in completes.  That means it's going to be undefined.

You're then using that undefined value to build a reference to a location in the database.  This is causing the actual reference to be something other than what you expect.  *You should add debug logging to see this yourself.*

You should be using the callback to determine when exactly the user is signed in, and only read and write that user's location.  This means that you should probably move the lines of code that write the database into the callback, when you know that `user` is correct, and use `user.uid` to build the database reference for reading and writing.